# String manipulation: calculate the "similarity of a string with its suffixes"

Tags: string, algorithm

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.

The problem is to give an algorithm to calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes. For example, let the string be : `ababaa`. Then, the suffixes of the string are `ababaa`, `babaa`, `abaa`, `baa`, `aa` and `a`. The similarities of each of these strings with the string `ababaa` are `6,0,3,0,1,1`, respectively. Thus the answer is `6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11`.

Comment: So did you try to solve it? Where did you get stuck? What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: Implementation of Ukkonen's algorithm to build a prefix tree in O(n)
https://gist.github.com/3355993

Comment: Ukkonen's algorithm is for building a *suffix* tree, which of course is precisely what this is about.  A suffix tree is not exactly the same thing as a suffix array, although they are obviously related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to consider [suffix arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). The suffix array of a word is the array of the indices of suffixes sorted in lexicographical order. In the linked wikipedia article, the algorithms compute the LCP (longest common prefix) as they compute the suffix array. You can compute this in `O(n)` using similarities with [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), as shown in [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.iastate.edu%2F~cs548%2Freferences%2Flinear_lcp.pdf&ei=UlDqTsj2LoqKiAKyh-nUBA&usg=AFQjCNE8jWaFo1BKSpP70vMnz8elisGRLg).

EXAMPLE: Your string is `ababaa`, so the suffix array looks like this:

```
5 | a
4 | aa
2 | abaa
0 | ababaa
3 | baa
1 | babaa
```

where the number on the left is the index at which the suffix begins. Now it's pretty each to compute prefixes since everything is stored lexicographically.

As a side note, this is closely related to the [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem. To practice for your next interview, think about ways to solve that efficiently.

Comment: :thanks a lot for this! I do understand what you are saying, but I am not familiar with suffix trees at all, and given the limited amount of time, I wanted to ask you, if you can looking at Knuth morris prat algotihm will help

Comment: @PengOne : I tried building Suffix tree, but the number of the  left i.e. LCP is between str[i - 1] and str[i], what they are looking for is between "ababaa" and "a" , "ababa" and "aa" , "ababaa" and "abaa" and so on.. where my solution fails becuase here I am doing linear comparasion, is there any more clue.

Comment: @PengOne Could you please explain how to solve this particular problem using suffix arrays? Or what benefit does a lexicographic ordering give to the solution as compared to manually comparing each suffix to the original string.

Comment: @PengOne What to do after making suffix array or even LCP?

Answer (score 1):

Read this link about [z-algorithm](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-similarity/topics/z-function) first.
An O(n) solution based on the algorithm from the link implemented on python:

```python
def z_func(s):
    z = [0]*len(s)
    l, r = 0, 0
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if i<=r:
            z[i] = min(r-i+1, z[i-l])
        while (i + z[i] < len(s) and s[z[i]] == s[i + z[i]]):
            z[i] += 1
        if z[i]+i-1 > r:
            l, r = i, z[i]+i-1
    return sum(z)+len(s)
```