# Suffix arrays in perl?

Tags: string, algorithm, perl

This question is closely related to [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525692/string-manipulation-calculate-the-similarity-of-a-string-with-its-suffixes). Looking for a very efficient solution to the question asked there. Have suffix arrays been implemented in perl ?

Here is my current solution in perl.

```
chomp(my $ipstr = <>);
my @bigstrchars = split(//, $ipstr);
my $length = (length $ipstr);
my $sum = 0;
my $span = 1;
my $flag = 0;
while ($span < $length) {
        for ($j=0; $j+$span<$length; $j++) {
                if ($bigstrchars[$j] eq $bigstrchars[$j+$span]) {
                        $sum++;
                }
                else {
                        last;
                }
        }
        if ($span == 1 && $sum == ($length-1)) {
             $sum = $length * ($length+1) * 0.5;
             $flag = 1;
             last;
        }
        $span++;
}
unless ($flag) {
    $sum += $length;
}
```

How can this be improved ?

EDIT

Stating the problem here :

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.

The problem is to give an algorithm to calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes. For example, let the string be : ababaa. Then, the suffixes of the string are ababaa, babaa, abaa, baa, aa and a. The similarities of each of these strings with the string ababaa are 6,0,3,0,1,1, respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11

Answer (score 2):

What about [Array::Suffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Array%3a%3aSuffix)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the algorithm correctly and you want to calculate the sum of longest common prefixes, your implementation is incorrect, since you're lacking the ascending lexicographic sort.

Here's one way to solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $ipstr = <>);    
my @subipstrs = map [split//], sort map{substr $ipstr, $_} 0 .. length($ipstr) - 1;
my $sum = 0;

for my $i (1 .. $#subipstrs) {
    my @last = @{$subipstrs[$i-1]};
    my @this = @{$subipstrs[$i]};
    my $j  = 0;
    $sum++ while $j < @last && $j < @this && $last[$j] eq $this[$j++];
}
```

For the example string `ababaa` in the question you refer to this will produce the suffix array

```
5 | a
4 | aa
2 | abaa   
0 | ababaa 
3 | baa
1 | babaa
```

represented by `@subipstrs`

```
@subipstrs = (
    ['a'],
    ['a', 'a'],
    ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'],
    ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'],
    ['b', 'a', 'a'],
    ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a']
);
```

This makes calculating `lcp`s a matter of comparing neighboring array refs element by element while pairs match, and adding up the total number of matches. The result is

```
5 | a      | 0
4 | aa     | 1
2 | abaa   | 1
0 | ababaa | 3
3 | baa    | 0
1 | babaa  | 2
```

With a total of **7**, not 11.

**EDIT:** This solves the problem you're interested in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $ipstr = <>);
my $len = my $sum = length($ipstr);

for my $i (1 .. $len -1) {
    my $substr = substr $ipstr, $i;
    chop $substr while $substr ne substr $ipstr, 0, length($substr);
    $sum += length($substr);
}
```

And is a bit faster than your solution with your example string and 1M iterations:

```
trinity  80906/s      --    -32%
flesk   119332/s     47%      --
```

**EDIT2:** This one's faster because it works from the start of the strings and are able to discard negative matches faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $ipstr = <>);
my $len = my $sum = length($ipstr);

for my $i (1 .. $len - 1) {
    my $ipstrcopy = reverse $ipstr;
    my $substr = reverse substr $ipstr, $i;
    my ($slen, $j) = (length($substr), 0);
    $sum++ while $j++ <= $slen && chop $ipstrcopy eq chop $substr;
}
```

`ababaa` and 100K iterations:

```
trinity  81967/s      --    -24%
flesk   107527/s     31%      --
```

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and 100K iterations:

```
trinity 26178/s      --    -15%
flesk   30769/s     18%      --
```

`aaaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaa` and 100K iterations:

```
trinity 5435/s      --    -30%
flesk   7800/s     44%      --
```

The algorithm can probably be improved further by reversing `$ipstr` before the loop or just using `substr`s instead of `chop`.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the problem statement, which is to calculate the sum of similarities of a string with all of its suffixes, NOT lcp. My solution is correct, only it doesn't use suffix arrays.

Comment: @trinity: I've edited in an updated solution. After some benchmarking I found that comparing suffix arrays were slower than comparing strings, but they are trivial to build with `split` in the same loop if needed.

Comment: Wow, this is an elegant solution ! Thank u :) My only concern now will be - though this speeds up for inputs like 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....', it slows down for 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.....' or 'aaaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbaaaaaaaaa'

Comment: @trinity: Yeah, that's true. I added an improved algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Flesk's solution is pretty elegant.  You asked for efficiency, then you asked for improvement.  When it comes to perl, I find whatever takes the less time to understand when coming back to it after 3 months to be the best improvement.  So take into consideration something a little more descriptive:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;

   main();

   sub main {
      my $string = "ababaa";                         # input string
      my $parts;                                     # hash ref
      my @suffixes = split '',$string;               # break input into tokens
      my $running_sum   = 0;
      $"='';

      # Build suffix tree
      for (0..$#suffixes){
         $parts->{"@suffixes"}=0;
         shift @suffixes;
      }


      # Compare suffixes to initial string
      for my $suffix (sort keys %$parts){
          $parts->{$suffix}  =  getMatches($suffix,$string);
          $running_sum      +=  $parts->{$suffix};
      }

      # Output
      $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys++;
      print Dumper($parts), "\nTotal Matches: $running_sum";
   }

   sub getMatches{
      my ($word,$string) = @_; 
      my $part    = '';
      my $offset  = 0;
      my $matches = 0;

      for (0..(length($word) - 1)){
         $offset++;
         $part = substr($word,0,$offset);
         if ($string =~ /^$part/){ $matches++; }
      }
      return $matches;
   }
```

There are obvious inefficiencies that could be improved (loops, regex comparison, subroutine call), but the point of this answer is an alternative to something that I've already identified as better for the only benefit of better future comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. :) Future comprehension is a major plus. I've had my share of scratching my head over 10 year old code that barely makes sense, as I'm sure many others on SO have too.

Comment: @flesk: definitely!  once i figure out something I did, it makes me feel like my younger self was smarter.  there are still needs for better performing code, but it seems like if I want my code to be faster I'll just spend the money to update the hardware :)  the only place I see a major need in better performing code these days is in handheld devices and it's not to be more efficient, but to save battery life