# For which scenarios my solution to this puzzle fails

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, testcase

For a problem puzzle framed as below

For two strings A and B, we define the similarity of the strings to be the length of the longest prefix common to both strings. For example, the similarity of strings "abc" and "abd" is 2, while the similarity of strings "aaa" and "aaab" is 3.
Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes.

I have written the following solution it is able to pass only three test cases , but i am not able to figure out the test cases for which it is failing , can you help me figure out the scenarios for which it fails.

Sample Input:
2
ababaa
aa

Sample Output:
11
3

Explanation:
For the first case, the suffixes of the string are "ababaa", "babaa", "abaa", "baa", "aa" and "a". The similarities of each of these strings with the string "ababaa" are 6,0,3,0,1,1 respectively. Thus the answer is 6 + 0 + 3 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 11.

For the second case, the answer is 2 + 1 = 3.

```
 def find_suffix(string):
        if len(string) == 0:
            return 0
        tail = 0
        head = 1
        occurences = [1]
        while head < len(string):
            if string[head] == string[tail]:
                occured = occurences[tail] + 1
                tail = tail + 1
            else:
                if string[0] == string[head]:
                    occured = 2
                    tail = 1
                else:
                    occured = 1
                    tail = 0

            occurences.append(occured)
            head = head + 1
        return sum(occurences)
```

Comment: "For two strings ..." - where are the two strings?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath  Sorry,I forgot to add the line Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes.added it now.

Comment: What are the test cases, and which fail?

Comment: I don't have access to the test cases but it only passes 3 test cases out out 10

Comment: "Calculate the sum of similarities of a string S with each of it's suffixes." - sorry, I don't understand this.. please give full description with examples and expected results.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance ?

Comment: @DaClown: random unrelated link?

Comment: One meassurement for the similarity of strings is their Levenshtein distance. Agreed? This is, up to a point, what the OP wants. I know this is not answer for the given question, more like hint for a possible solution, but then it's also not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @DaClown: I don't see how this could be a hint. If you do, you misunderstood his question.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525692/string-manipulation-calculate-the-similarity-of-a-string-with-its-suffixes looks the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python. I wrote this code in scheme language. It works in DrRacket

```
(define inp-string (read))

(define inp-list (string->list inp-string))

(define (sim-len l1 l2)
  (cond ((or (null? l1) (null? l2)) 0)
        ((char=? (car l1) (car l2)) (+ 1 (sim-len (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))
        (else
          0)))

(define inp-strlen (string-length inp-string))

(define iter-cnt 0)
(define final-ans 0)

(define (sum-of-sim l)
 (define (iter count)
   (cond ((null? l) 0)
         ((= iter-cnt inp-strlen) 0)
         (else
         (set! final-ans (+ final-ans 
         (sim-len inp-list (string->list (substring inp-string iter-cnt inp-strlen)))))
           (set! iter-cnt (+ iter-cnt 1))
    (iter iter-cnt))))
(iter iter-cnt))

(sum-of-sim inp-list)

final-ans
```

The cases i tested were as follows:

Input :-  ""  final-ans =0,  Input :-  "r" final-ans =1,  Input :-  "rajesh" final-ans =6,  Input :-  "rajesh bhat" final-ans=11,  Input :-  "rajraj" final-ans =9,  Input :-  "aaaaaa" final-ans =21

What are the other cases? Hope this helps.

Comment: my solution passed all these test cases as well, so still not able to figure out for which scenarios it fails.